# Gradient Fill disappears when I save image

Tags: gimp

I am having trouble using the gradient fill in GIMP.  Sometimes it stays, but sometimes is disappears when I save the file. What am I missing?  I have tried doing it on the same layer as where I made the selection and on a new layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gimp 2.10 you have to strike [Enter] to commit your action. Switching tools also does it, but exporting the file doesn't.

Comment: that is such an annoyance! Took me 20 min to find out. Do you know why the feature?

Comment: Because the UI is more powerful, it's no linger click+drag, you can now adjust all the parameters at your leisure. The Enter/double click indicates you are really done. This is also true of the new UI of selection tools.